# Transfer Database From LAMP to WAMP

Tags: mysql, wamp, lamp

I had a hosting server made from an old laptop(ubuntu server) :). for fun I hosted a few of my websites from home and had one database with one table in it with approximately 500 000 records(this is the only thing i need from there). The old laptop broke but my hard disk is functioning.
How can I transfer this database into WAMP becuse I don't want to make a lamp server. 
I would like to use xampp.

Comment: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,33258,33258. There are hundreds of articles on it

Comment: Is it a MYIASM or INNODB database. What version of MySQL were you running on old laptop and what version of MySQL are you running on the new WAMP system

Comment: I don't remember  my database version was the latest approximately 2 years ago.

Comment: Is it possible to install virtualbox and make it boot from external hard which allready contens the os?